# Behavior of clojurescript `and` function with integers is confusing

Tags: integer, boolean, clojurescript

Probably just showcasing my ignorance of lisp(s) here, but I have some slightly odd results with ClojureScript's `and` function:

```
(and true false) ; false
(and false true) ; false
(and 1 0)        ; 0
(and 0 1)        ; 1 !?
```

What's going on here? I'd at least expect symmetry; is this something to do with the bit-storage of `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`and` returns its last argument if all the arguments are truthy, otherwise it returns `false` (it also stops evaluating the arguments as soon as it reaches the first falsey one). In Clojure, unlike Javascript, `0` and `1` are both truthy. The only falsey values in Clojure are `false` and `nil`.

http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-truthy-and-falsey.html

Comment: What's the use-case for that sort of behavior (returning last thing if all truthy)?

Comment: Something like `(and arg (.getName arg))` which returns the name unless `arg` is `nil`. Or `(and (not= denominator 0) (/ numerator denominator))` to prevent divide by zero.

Comment: BTW, Javascript `&&` works the same way. Similarly Clojure `or` and Javascript `||` return the first truthy value. These operators do short-circuiting in most languages, although some languages just return a boolean (e.g. PHP and C) while others return the last value examined (Javascript and most Lisp-like languages).

Comment: Thanks - now I think about it, before Python had if-else allowed in statements, that's how we did these sorts of things, too.